# How do you change EditText line/field color on TextInputLayout (when calling setError)?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

When I invoke `setError` on the `TextInputLayout` from the [new Android design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) the line color does not change. But the error does successfully appear with the correct color.

This is the code I'm using:

```
textInputLayout.setError("Error Message");
```

Per the [Material Design Spec for Text Fields](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html) when there is an error, the line/field color should be red.

**How can I set the color of the line?**

If it can be done as a side effect of invoking `setError` that would be great.

Comment: BTW, it appears as though this is a bug so I'm looking for a workaround. Thanks! https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175672&thanks=175672&ts=1433368432

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add

`editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);`

After your

`textInputLayout.setError("Error Message");`.

Comment: Works fine but still the label has primary color?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with API 21+. There was a fix added to the 23.1.0 support library, but it seems to have regressed with 23.1.1 (which was needed to fix a more serious TextInputLayout bug). Hopefully, they will get this widget completely fixed soon.